# make this plugin able to swipe in desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I found this light and great slider plugin
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ximan/swipeSlide/master/js/swipeSlide.js
that work great in mobile but I also want it to be able to swipe in desktop.

Then in the swipeSlide.js,

I replaced this `var events = ['touchstart','touchmove','touchend'];` to this `var events = ['mousedown','mousemove','mouseup'];`
but the behavior is not right.

DEMO is [here](http://ons.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/swipeSlide/full-screen-pic.html), to see it working u have to switch into mobile mode (using chrome inspection tool)

Comment: if you think the plugin isn't work they way it should raise a bug on github

Comment: @atmd that is not a bug, it's just that the author didn't make it work on desktop.